# Need clarification on the ways to wait for a task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

```
var task = Xyz.Start();
task.ContinueWith((ant)=> Validate());
task.Wait();
```

vs

```
var task1 = Xyz.Start();
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith((ant)=> Validate());
task2.Wait();
```

Recently I came across a SO question(Sorry can't remember which one) and the OP's sample code was like the one on the top.  The accepted answer corrected the code as in the bottom without any explanation.

So what's the difference between the two code snippets and why is the bottom one is correct? I thought `task1.ContinueWith()` is effectively `task1.Wait()` meaning the execution will not continue until task1 returns.

Comment: Does search for code (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=var+task2+%3D+task1.ContinueWith((ant)%3D>+Validate())%3B) finds question you are asking about?

Comment: In first you wait for your task, in second you wait for your continuation.

Answer (score 2):

`ContinueWith` does not wait. It registers a callback to be executed when the task completes. Maybe you should check out the documentation for `ContinueWith` to see this explained more completely.

Which form you need depends on what you want. If you want to continue only after the continuation is done you need to wait on `task2`.

Comment: The issue I am having is that the continuewith is not executed or rather the callback, no matter if I wait on task.wait or task2.wait.  The idea is if task1 throws exception, the callback in the continuewith will be called.  As soon as the task1 throws exception the main thread exits. If I try catch the task1.wait(), I can examine the exception.  But it should be examined inside the continuewith's callback.

Comment: If you wait on task2 this should work. Post complete code that reproduced the problem.

Comment: I am working on a signalR project. The only changes from above is: var task1 = hubConnection.Start()

Answer (score 1):

> I thought `task1.ContinueWith()` is effectively `task1.Wait()` meaning the execution will not continue until `task1` returns.

No. `ContinueWith()` makes sure that the execution of the delegate you pass to starts only after the `Task` completes. But it doesn't block the execution of the code that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if we read the code its fairly straight forward

```
//Start initial task
Task initTask = Xyz.Start();
//Continue initial task with something
Task continueTask = initTask.ContinueWith((obj)=> { /*work work*/ }); 

//Wait for the initial task to finish (not the continue)
initTask.Wait();
//Wait for the continue task to finish
continueTask.Wait();
```